# jquery each() + serialize getJson

Tags: jquery, .when

I have a form where are listed documents to be forwarded 
each invoice has a checkbox
I made this routine to send all checked documents

```
.....
$('.send-flag ').each(function() {
    if ($(this)[0].checked==true)
    {
        DocID=$(this).val();
        $('.loading').html('<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x"></i>');
        var Payload = '&docid='+DocID
        $.getJSON(formURL+Payload).done(function(data){
            if (data.Status=='OK')
            {
                var msg=data.Message;
                msgA=msg.split('.');
                $('#ckb'+msgA[0]).prop('checked', true);
                $('.'+msg).addClass('sent').removeClass('unsent');
                $('#snack_ok span').html(data.Payload);
                $('.loading').html('');
                $('#snack_ok').addClass('active-snack');
                setTimeout(function(){$('#snack_ok').removeClass('active-snack');},5000);
            }
        });
    }
});
....
```

problem grows as the number of checked documents arise:
since the (php) routine performs several tasks on the database, command overlaps and routine stucks:

I need to modify in way that a new document is processed after the previous has been sent: in other words call should be serialized, or, in other words it should work syncronously

I thought using `$.when` could be a solution, but have no idea how to embed it in the `each()` function:

Can somebody supply a suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: `$(this)[0]` <= don't do this.  This is logically the same as `# + 1 - 1`.  You're doing unnecessary work.

Comment: `$.when()` does not force syncronicity.  It simply is a logical construct to wait for all asynchronous requests to be done, and then perform a callback.  To make the requests 'synchronous', you're going to have to refactor the logic so that it only performs one request at a time, and starts the next request once it's done.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for suggestion, but if I put [0] probably only $(this) did not work.

Comment: You're missing the point.  `$(this)[0] === this` ... `[0]` breaks the element out of the jQuery object.  So you are taking an Element, making a jQuery object with it, and then breaking the Element out.  So the creation of the jQuery object is pointless.

Comment: OK, will avoid $.when, but I would like to avoid to fully rebuild the routine (since this is only a small part): 
I was wondering to invert the script and make getJSON call itself in .done() but no idea where put .each()

Comment: You will not use an each().  `each()` is not built for asynchronicity in mind.  You will need to create a form of a recursive loop, that continues to process the next action, while actions are still remaining to be processed.

Comment: I see.. well, actually not fully understand what you mean: I will try to learn a bit more

Comment: Consider this dummy little example: https://jsfiddle.net/d89cbv1r/

Comment: you mean, use .each() to build the thingsToProcess Array, and then in the function put the getJSON, and in the .done() recall the function itself?

Comment: The things to process would be your `$('.send-flag')` in your case, no?

Comment: yes, right. it is there